# Passing Variables into List.FindAll

Tags: c#, findall

I have been constructing a Game template as a means of testing my newly learned abilities at C# and I have been working on a method that returns a list of Objects from another list Objects. But I only wanted a list of certain Objects (the type is inputted as a parameter)

```
newObjectList = area.getSpecificObjects(Tile)
```

I have worked on the function

```
public List<Object> getSpecificObjects(System.Type type)
{
    List<Object> searchObjects = objects.Objects; //Returns a List of Objects from the class ObjectList
    System.Type searchType = type;

    return (searchObjects.FindAll(
        delegate(Object obj)
        {
            return obj is searchType;
        })
    );
}
```

However my attempt of producing a method has failed. The "searchtype" variable in the delegate section keeps returning the error "The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Can anyone recommend a correct way of writing such a function or advise me on why my attempt has failed? Ideally the latter as I can learn more that way. I have searched on StackOverflow and currently can't find my answer as to why my function has failed.

Comment: is `objects` some kind of inner object in your class? Aside from this you should use `area.getSpecificObjects(typeof(Tile))` to get the runtime `Type`

Comment: The objects is part of the area class. It is an ObjectList class (a list of Objects)

Comment: And I will note that down for when I use the command. When I can find a fix for it

Comment: you should consider learning a bit more about generics and LINQ ... as soon as you fire a LINQ question here you will get 5 answers in no time ;)

Comment: I will definitely use LINQ in the future. I hear it is highly received. Right now I want to ensure I have C# down and happy :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek ... this will give you an error - `searchType` is not the Name of a class but a type-representation - you have to use `x => x.GetType() == searchType` instead

Comment: Well done Marcin, the error has stopped. I will just test it and give the thumbs up/down

Comment: Thanks everyone. That has done the trick. I now have a way of finding specific objects. Much obliged everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`is` is a "compile-time" operator which means that you can't use it with object of type `Type`.

Here is a proper way to implement your method:

```
public class Finder
    {
        public static List<T> GetSpecificObjects<T>(List<Object> source)
        {
            return (List<T>) source.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof (T));
        }
    }
```

Ofc, if you don't know type in compile-time you can use an implementation with `Type`

```
public static List<Object> GetSpecificObjects(Type t, List<Object> source)
        {
            return source.Where(item => item.GetType() == t).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

as you don't want to use LINQ or Generics yet here is a working version of your code:

```
newObjectList = area.getSpecificObjects(typeof(Tile));

public List<Object> getSpecificObjects(System.Type searchType)
{
    List<Object> searchObjects = objects.Objects; //Returns a List of Objects from the class ObjectList

    return (searchObjects.FindAll(
        delegate(Object obj)
        {
            return obj.GetType() == searchType;
        })
    );
}
```

PS: you used LINQ already with `.FindAll` ;)

Comment: I did? Huh. Love it when I use stuff without knowing I did :P

And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone. This is what you have helped me produce.

```
public List<Object> getSpecificObjects(System.Type type)
{
    List<Object> searchObjects = objects.Objects; //Returns a List of Objects from the class ObjectList
    System.Type searchType = type;

    return (searchObjects.FindAll(x => x.GetType() == searchType));
}
```